# C# and Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#

I'm setting up a test system controlled with C# using XUnit, selenium webdrive, with the Collections Fixture pattern.

Currently my project is separated by test folders, login, dashboard, users, etc...

How could I create a new class, with a robot, where I'll start the tests through it and it would call the tests that I left configured? Could anyone tell me?

public void RunLogin()
{
using (var runner = AssemblyRunner.WithoutAppDomain(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
{
runner.Start(type => type.Name.StartsWith("LoginTests"));
}
}

```
    public void RunDashboard()
    {
        using (var runner = AssemblyRunner.WithoutAppDomain(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
        {
            runner.Start(type => type.Name.StartsWith("DashboardTests"));
        }
    }
```